# random rowcount in PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo

how would i get a random rowcount using PDO? i'm still learning how to use PDO so this is what i tried, but it didn't work because it doesn't randomize the quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM thquotes;";

                 try {
                      $query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
                      $query->execute();

                      **$rowcount = $query->rowCount();
                      $rand = rand(0,$rowcount-1);**

                      $sql = "SELECT cQuotes, vAuthor, cArabic, vReference 
                              FROM thquotes 
                              LIMIT $rand, 1";
```

i was using this code earlier without PDO which worked:

```
**$rowcount = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
$rand = rand(0,$rowcount-1);**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with MySQL as well:

```
$sql = "SELECT cQuotes, vAuthor, cArabic, vReference 
                              FROM thquotes 
                              ORDER BY RAND()
                              LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are planning on working with large amounts of data, I would suggest against using ORDER BY Rand().

For the explanation / reasoning and an alternative method see: [Titov.Net - Do not use Order By RAND()](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/)'s article.

Answer (score 2):

To get the lines in a random order, add `ORDER BY RAND()`.